# Remove legend border of rectangle in piechart

Tags: jfreechart

I am trying to set the legend item shape as rectangular using the below code. But I always see a black border around the rectangle. How do I remove it. I tried few things like setting legend border to zero, setting plot setOutlineVisible to false, but none worked

```
plot.setLegendItemShape(new Rectangle(8,6));
```

Full customizer code used within Jaspersoft Studio

```
public class PieCustomizer extends JRAbstractChartCustomizer{
public void customize(JFreeChart chart, JRChart jasperChart){

    PiePlot plot = (PiePlot) chart.getPlot();

    plot.setShadowXOffset(0);
    plot.setShadowYOffset(0);

    plot.setLegendItemShape(new Rectangle(8,6));
    LegendTitle legend = chart.getLegend();
    legend.setFrame(BlockBorder.NONE);
    legend.setPosition(RectangleEdge.LEFT);
    legend.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.BOTTOM);

    plot.setSectionOutlinesVisible(false);
    plot.setDirection(Rotation.ANTICLOCKWISE);
    plot.setLabelLinkPaint(new Color(103,103,103));
    plot.setLabelOutlinePaint(Color.BLUE);
    plot.setLabelShadowPaint(Color.WHITE);
    }
}
```

[Screenshot (can't paste inline image due to insufficient reputation points)](http://uploadpie.com/iOxZK)

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: @Jes I have added the full customizer code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rectangles are drawn using the `sectionOutlinePaint` and `sectionOutlineStroke`.

If you wish to make them invisible, you can set the following for all keys in the dataset:

```
plot.setSectionOutlinePaint(key, Color.WHITE);
plot.setSectionOutlineStroke(key ,new BasicStroke(0f));
```

If you wish to remove the border around the legend box, you should set the border of the `LegendTitle` object:

```
legend.setBorder(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: I tried this, but didn't work :(. Still see the border around the rectangle

Comment: Oh now I get it. I must have misunderstood your question. My answer applies to the box around the legends. Take a look at my updated answer.

Comment: I am using JasperSoft Studio. Where exactly do I put this line to suppress the legend border: legend.setBorder(0, 0, 0, 0);?